# creating regex pattern in validation.xml in Struts

Tags: regex, struts

i am new to regex being used in validation.xml in struts 1.0.
that said, what does the following mean? in terms of xx/xx/xxxx?

```
<constant-value>^\d{1,2}(\-|\/|\.)\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$</constant-value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a date validator in any of the following formats:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
dd/mm/yyyy
dd.mm.yyyy

mm-dd-yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
mm.dd.yyyy
```

PS: It allows month or date digits to be single or double digits.

[**Recommended Regex Reference**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: what if i what it to be only in mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: That is probably possible with regex but it will be an awfully long regex validating all possible days of a month like July/31, Nov/30. Moreover for leap year that will fail. IMO better to validate dates using code while using a regex like above to make sure basic syntax is there.

Comment: okthanks. do i have to look at `validator-rules.xml`? there is a `validator=date` and `datePatternStrict` so should I be concerned too?

Comment: Actually `validator=date` seems to the best fit for you as per: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/date-validator.html

Comment: @anubhava Wrong version of Struts.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Ah thanks, forgot that OP is using Struts 1.0

Comment: @LaneLane: In that case use above regex for basic date validation.